# trivial linux sound playback

Tags: linux, audio

The classical C program is something like:

```
int main() { fprintf(stderr, "hello world\n"); }
```

a classical OpenGL program is:

```
open up a window
setup ortho view
draw a colored triangle
```

Now, I want to do the most basic thing for sound in Linux.

I want to:

```
1) open up speakers
2) send a bunch of data, meant to be interpreted at 40Khz,
3) have pseakers play said data
```

no midi, no instruments, ... just playing back raw data

What is the easiest way to do this in a C program? [and what libraries; what's the equiv to OpenGL for sound?]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound equivalent of OpenGL is OpenAL library. It is cross-platform, whereas ALSA is Linux-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Linux has two sound API:s: the older [Open Sound System](http://www.opensound.com/) (OSS), and the current [Advanced Linux Sound Architecture](http://alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page) (ALSA).

ALSA is not renowned for being extremely easy to get going with; it's possible that the [smallest "hello world"](http://www.equalarea.com/paul/alsa-audio.html#playex)-type app will frighten you. It's mostly verbose due to error-checking though.

You can also use the fact that the default output device is generally mapped as /dev/dsp, so you can just write bits into it and have them played back.

Answer (score 0):

There is a counterpart to OpenGL called, unsurprisingly, [OpenAL](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/default.aspx).